# Как настроить CI так, чтобы увеличить процент покрытия тестами перед каждым Merge Request?

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci, jacoco

Моя компания использует GitLab CI, unit/integration test coverage на данный момент составляет около 60% для проекта, над которым я работаю.

Мы используем библиотеку JaCoCo для расчета покрытия тестами. Есть ли способ настроить GitLab CI таким образом, чтобы смержить новый код можно было только при условии повышения покрытия (на 0.2-0.5% например)?

Comment: Преимущество gitlab ci в том, что вашу проблему можно решить по разному :) Например, в job внутри которой вы запускаете JaCoCo, добавить "allow_failure: false", что будет сигнализировать о том, что следующие job не могут быть запущены, если это завершился с ошибкой, далее можно в секции "script" или даже в "after_script" проверить результат выполнения JaCoCo средствами bash, можно сравнить результат покрытия который получился сейчас, с предыдущим результатом, и сделать например "exit 1". Что будет означать что этот job завершился с ошибкой

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный вариант, Евгений